# OpsWorks + EC2 getting whitelistable IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-opsworks, elastic-ip

I'm trying to determine how I can get a block range or static IP address out of my server stack. I'm using OpsWorks and EC2 and I have a main API server and a bunch of clustered workers. I'll have to white label the whole stack and all the IP addresses contained in it for a number of external services.

I've attempted reading documentation on Elastic IPs and the built in Load Balancer but I can't seem to determine which IPs I can depend on.

Thanks.

Comment: The question is not quite clear to me, do you mean you have EIP for API server and all worker servers that you want to get their EIP from outside? Do you want to manually run a script to get IPs then add them to your external system?

Comment: We're using a pretty antiquated SMS dispatch service and they will unfortunately not accept a DNS value, they explicitly when us to provide IP addresses of our boxes. Basically I cannot automate that process with them, I have to provide them either with a single static IP or a block of static IPs. Thanks for your help C.B.

Answer (score 0):

Setup your [AWS Opsworks infrastructure inside VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingstacks-vpc.html) with [NAT](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/6079781443936876). You would then need to ONLY provide the ElasticIP address for a given STACK's VPC NAT box.